# How do you indent code block for scaladoc

Tags: scala, scaladoc, scala-2.11

I wrote a comment like this:

```
/** Blah blah blah.
  *
  * {{{
  * class MyAppServlet extends ControllerServlet {
  *   routes.publishWithReflection("/main", MainController)
  *   routes.publishWithReflection("/foo", FooController)
  * }
  * }}}
  *
  * Blah blah blah
  */
```

I want the code to indent, but here's what the generated HTML looks like:

[image]

Is this a bug, or ... ?  I'm using Scala 2.11.0.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there is a bug in the scaladoc generator which makes proper indenting not possible. The bug was found and is solved in pull request https://github.com/scala/scala/pull/3951. There may be no backport to Scala 2.10 though.